# Trouble changing legend items in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to execute volcano plot even though I am not getting expected results
So I am plotting my results like this:

[image]

The code to get to this is sthg like this

```
ggplot(data=volcano, aes(x=log2RQ_avg_group_gen, y=-log10(p.value_t.test), colour=diffexp, label=delabel)) +
        geom_point() + 
        geom_text_repel() +
        scale_color_manual(values=c("gray48", "aquamarine3", "red")) +
        geom_vline(xintercept=c(-0.6, 0.6), col="red") +
        geom_hline(yintercept=-log10(0.05), col="red")+
        labs(x = "Log2(Fold-change)", y = "-log10p.value",
       title = "Genes diferentially expressed") + 
  theme(legend.title = element_text("Changes in gene expression"))
```

What I wanted to do is change the legend, and where right now there is diffexp, I would like to remove it, and put "Genes diferentially expressed". I have tried several approaches, but none of them seem to override the name of diffexp. Of course I could change the name of the column, but I think there is no need for that, and you could change the plot without changing the column. In fact, the values inside the legend "No change" and "Upregulated" were done by me, changing the values in column. But I insist just to prove it, I would like to customize my legend without editing my dataframe

Thank you in adavance.

The database example

```
volcano <- structure(list(gen = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 
34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 
39L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 
43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 47L, 
47L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
52L, 52L, 52L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 55L, 55L, 55L), levels = c("abca1", 
"abcg1", "adrb2", "b2m", "cav1", "ccl3", "cd36", "cd40l", "cd68", 
"cd86", "cdkn2a", "chuk", "cxcl2", "cxcl8_il8_", "cyp27a1", "dusp1", 
"gapd", "icam1", "ido", "ifng", "il10", "il1b", "il23a", "il8ra", 
"il8rb", "lag3", "ldlr", "lrp1", "mcp1", "msr1", "mttp", "nampt", 
"nfe2l2", "nfkb1", "nlrp1", "nlrp3", "nr1h2", "nr1h3", "olr1", 
"pcsk9", "pik3cb", "ppara", "ppard", "pparg", "ptgs1", "ptgs2", 
"rxra", "rxrb", "s18", "s1pr3", "scarb1", "slc2a3_glut3_", "tgfb2", 
"tnf", "vcam1"), class = "factor"), grup_int = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), levels = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
    log2RQ_avg_group_gen = c(0.673827751773452, 0.678629982739449, 
    0.843447924636187, 0.446637368687918, 0.559689915970579, 
    0.347591714282748, 0.235236889089815, 0.357511789561679, 
    0.504366150612272, -0.393500918011677, -0.086565729568521, 
    -0.160443456245703, 0.372283512880528, 0.318791979496838, 
    0.683398559096208, 0.334591157245834, 0.562134826927875, 
    0.61847360308248, 0.45149863291133, 0.43465263507229, 0.481074261190024, 
    0.277294468272469, 0.436542608152177, 0.381837083906047, 
    0.488556140090397, 0.492182817515178, 0.642123916153488, 
    0.235408467796342, 0.310450922427872, 0.396919967709548, 
    0.150692295506475, 0.356063300443124, 0.61390485091015, 0.165429620424185, 
    0.203335416708583, 0.370977950568322, 0.323704401197589, 
    0.602194418956636, 0.57370454933218, 0.248971950228037, 0.796557238011432, 
    0.57796742791765, 0.46194758214236, 0.518940385226588, 0.395696544054752, 
    0.279388089411629, 0.469563522577392, 0.51127826508303, 0.338206088161101, 
    0.0964922498030038, 0.288465380320154, 0.639309351930224, 
    0.572797296033061, 0.440073999630787, 0.401586780986442, 
    0.266578141437752, 0.61998306686984, 0.0102069428692571, 
    0.28130380465971, 0.52332194145487, 0.347529600058606, 0.39380459235653, 
    0.597709935768445, 0.321812674667221, 0.513947869486528, 
    0.29620839769131, -0.0551115764251454, 0.619312389045996, 
    0.0175001970242938, 0.566669050912804, 0.725065944152723, 
    0.413499896344778, 0.477698048350665, 0.557012518875856, 
    0.666011970081795, 0.526128922708653, 0.502690755428565, 
    0.760593550201907, 0.609868406863344, 0.56979196925138, 0.64101466056571, 
    1.08542465625268, 1.03003333038981, 0.871942189887102, 0.394906061504399, 
    0.731924959871834, 0.438913804353281, 0.404401796593496, 
    0.359137153949314, 0.571353208771595, 1.33084518962342, 0.928275561611935, 
    0.340847077050414, 0.29080183806501, 0.48004349289036, 0.369303615801434, 
    0.273551695546287, 0.442697103242763, 0.291501061135854, 
    0.499006488607375, 0.530165891114872, 0.510100029898664, 
    0.628204335631376, 0.851637214089901, 0.741251240170613, 
    0.46335042198875, 0.379981313580385, 0.403978993532454, 0.282878625962085, 
    0.560319003200308, 0.569788663248465, 0.270671937280388, 
    0.485040339234487, 0.393111068379105, 0.0683866845826684, 
    0.407650570458169, 0.204792829504966, 1.1479578813871, 0.53173494247986, 
    0.6535186707536, 0.467696836372603, 0.496036184973107, 0.602864618527252, 
    0.390178512022425, 0.143945934861479, 0.670675560021536, 
    0.391437797698, 0.556517002799925, 0.519395128345851, 0.287377727822054, 
    0.340805401339202, 0.472675804565665, 0.622761714371511, 
    0.754602497215705, 0.532067552289031, 0.489481280690825, 
    0.535356258603784, 0.477578128193518, 0.477718768838423, 
    0.444818491144423, 0.526878608163742, 0.503104448659552, 
    0.339300300061861, 0.561612928525255, 0.197135683632034, 
    0.426839800896208, 0.49618535690636, 0.453375343939143, 0.725481496842538, 
    0.70600948743508, 0.282736320276342, 0.459510308947993, 0.513183125333938, 
    0.599203516297803, 0.560738242342065, 0.760138374013093, 
    0.90867960548252, 0.79416332619722, 0.756260194546978, 0.379953597427636, 
    0.34117250310286, 0.505413961184672, 0.897971808109291, 0.990945554158038, 
    0.752106299325194), p.value_lme = c(0.262, 0.262, 0.262, 
    0.186, 0.186, 0.186, 0.868, 0.868, 0.868, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 
    0.189, 0.189, 0.189, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.657, 0.657, 0.657, 
    0.986, 0.986, 0.986, 0.179, 0.179, 0.179, 0.382, 0.382, 0.382, 
    0.557, 0.557, 0.557, 0.542, 0.542, 0.542, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 
    0.438, 0.438, 0.438, 0.055, 0.055, 0.055, 0.641, 0.641, 0.641, 
    0.097, 0.097, 0.097, 0.345, 0.345, 0.345, 0.023, 0.023, 0.023, 
    0.081, 0.081, 0.081, 0.051, 0.051, 0.051, 0.037, 0.037, 0.037, 
    0.785, 0.785, 0.785, 0.327, 0.327, 0.327, 0.082, 0.082, 0.082, 
    0.011, 0.011, 0.011, 0.298, 0.298, 0.298, 0.832, 0.832, 0.832, 
    0.93, 0.93, 0.93, 0.104, 0.104, 0.104, 0.415, 0.415, 0.415, 
    0.034, 0.034, 0.034, 0.015, 0.015, 0.015, 0.541, 0.541, 0.541, 
    0.845, 0.845, 0.845, 0.042, 0.042, 0.042, 0.209, 0.209, 0.209, 
    0.92, 0.92, 0.92, 0.713, 0.713, 0.713, 0.737, 0.737, 0.737, 
    0.778, 0.778, 0.778, 0.938, 0.938, 0.938, 0.339, 0.339, 0.339, 
    0.896, 0.896, 0.896, 0.353, 0.353, 0.353, 0.101, 0.101, 0.101, 
    0.305, 0.305, 0.305, 0.521, 0.521, 0.521, 0.366, 0.366, 0.366, 
    0.651, 0.651, 0.651, 0.918, 0.918, 0.918, 0.258, 0.258, 0.258, 
    0.359, 0.359, 0.359, 0.667, 0.667, 0.667, 0.702, 0.702, 0.702
    ), p.value_t.test = c(0.0030615496082387, 0.316791643325235, 
    0.0113557257326085, 0.0520729463012179, 0.51583864304924, 
    0.0822794139975383, 0.038027189929274, 0.673030472137914, 
    0.0871317193444053, 0.0180678989230183, 0.0582716013329099, 
    0.0147644537498152, 0.41677001490964, 0.287584815432068, 
    0.16276142594134, 0.0781153475411008, 0.384372599151743, 
    0.0326227722821529, 0.00365265131356199, 0.328742335279695, 
    0.0366676481229433, 0.0301421783557575, 0.431345082283611, 
    0.163827564946798, 0.000821274641131046, 0.428122835766029, 
    0.0260136950429, 0.228172080136452, 0.94425454843297, 0.239241154789132, 
    0.453913299960223, 0.471035211882313, 0.0681797442577486, 
    0.242557589640248, 0.85639887998269, 0.310890532181496, 0.0657241831057335, 
    0.322388806787908, 0.0143837438151795, 0.531823312412664, 
    0.106127815933092, 0.338206452715055, 0.0242143470774075, 
    0.386253405935062, 0.0885436377890862, 0.184116624521057, 
    0.755002949319586, 0.064774006615063, 0.0519773739813334, 
    0.783506342203665, 0.187199884471608, 0.000105045183878225, 
    0.237491947104653, 0.0587147440986507, 0.0868604653007271, 
    0.436731691769318, 0.456099276206823, 0.2969201092462, 0.829001355289693, 
    0.202575649435648, 0.0940418309637224, 0.590244960972639, 
    0.0431735032429566, 0.0511524731808517, 0.415396931700432, 
    0.189343202825911, 0.254657496592373, 0.988558911856724, 
    0.315463106781792, 0.0105816975103229, 0.139321214938155, 
    0.0583182653479684, 0.073445202370579, 0.119990924437495, 
    0.0194112455692662, 0.00102687600220635, 0.0945194626279092, 
    0.00485024940530741, 0.000694972849189659, 0.205177469143194, 
    0.00557982417741832, 3.58156351613892e-08, 0.0245152667125237, 
    0.00858807694419658, 0.0878439424626319, 0.854574927693542, 
    0.632885767673194, 0.134417163274472, 0.870919991830926, 
    0.0395446363029076, 0.00193837522198661, 0.274673003210613, 
    0.469040106298858, 0.280188248683647, 0.965301007748228, 
    0.713249874818307, 0.15947365233815, 0.599837687782857, 0.0592061398738306, 
    0.00416633540386246, 0.284232363156883, 0.254425602982701, 
    0.00119454095056321, 0.0828975079433397, 0.00575341940316349, 
    0.00502153348871103, 0.387025786292937, 0.0347765898324957, 
    0.0568528684223361, 0.417340726639012, 0.0510747967349023, 
    0.329918267105925, 0.421702633505541, 0.0496229819322505, 
    0.428788771632911, 0.417403132143341, 0.471059682506238, 
    0.588186234792912, 0.719109301347357, 0.337408270067066, 
    0.012516644728542, 0.508647168602849, 0.0309271296687206, 
    0.326618598525058, 0.263519781573862, 0.172952183808972, 
    0.00666349166008389, 0.161299382206212, 0.0973065309760128, 
    0.114505290368661, 0.968419515633973, 0.393363311443396, 
    0.00017314254904102, 0.357806658716716, 0.475078368287757, 
    0.0220025532579411, 0.257617088056722, 0.0403840121920654, 
    0.00294432159942567, 0.234809255957901, 0.135363026196834, 
    0.000373473578379636, 0.810433217432754, 0.136392179221139, 
    0.107691858160653, 0.0923934243916721, 0.173287014136683, 
    0.0105977127463626, 0.482859575799261, 0.0594723669778892, 
    0.173220515398002, 0.430707263095507, 0.0372555575574926, 
    0.00746034626834429, 0.203971906599985, 0.0215995461352047, 
    1.3029557711511e-05, 0.17377623883927, 0.005458338911701, 
    0.00121856713685668, 0.524660512453469, 0.0462893415464844, 
    0.0204387053962217, 0.0763864531041156, 0.0940850732097377
    ), diffexp = c("Upregulated", "No change", "Upregulated", 
    "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", 
    "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", 
    "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", "Upregulated", 
    "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", 
    "No change", "No change", "No change", "Upregulated", "No change", 
    "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", 
    "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", 
    "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", 
    "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", 
    "No change", "No change", "No change", "Upregulated", "No change", 
    "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", 
    "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", 
    "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", 
    "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", 
    "No change", "Upregulated", "No change", "No change", "Upregulated", 
    "Upregulated", "No change", "Upregulated", "Upregulated", 
    "Upregulated", "Upregulated", "No change", "No change", "No change", 
    "No change", "No change", "No change", "Upregulated", "No change", 
    "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", 
    "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", 
    "Upregulated", "No change", "Upregulated", "No change", "No change", 
    "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", 
    "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", 
    "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", 
    "Upregulated", "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", 
    "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", 
    "Upregulated", "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", 
    "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", 
    "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", 
    "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", "No change", 
    "No change", "No change", "No change", "Upregulated", "Upregulated", 
    "No change", "Upregulated", "No change", "No change", "No change", 
    "Upregulated", "No change", "No change"), delabel = c("abca1", 
    NA, "abca1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, "ccl3", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "cd68", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "icam1", NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, "il8rb", NA, NA, "lag3", "ldlr", NA, "ldlr", 
    "lrp1", "lrp1", "lrp1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "mttp", NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "nlrp1", NA, "nlrp1", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, "pik3cb", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "ptgs1", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "slc2a3_glut3_", "tgfb2", NA, 
    "tgfb2", NA, NA, NA, "vcam1", NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-165L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Try with `+ labs(..., color = "Genes diferentially expressed", title = "Changes in gene expression")`. And get rid of `theme(legend.title = element_text("Changes in gene expression"))`.

Comment: ... and to set the labels without editing your df you could use `+ scale_color_manual(..., labels = c(...))`

Comment: It worked. This :+ scale_color_manual(..., labels = c(...)) can change labels, but can change keys?

Comment: The legend keys are a different issue. Keys are set by the geom, e.g. a "point" for geom_point, a "rectangle" for geom_col. But you can do some hacks via `guide_legend`.